# Inputs have same CSS height, but different rendered heights

Tags: html, css

I set 2 `<input>`'s heights as `2em` using CSS, but the heights are rendered differently in Google Chrome. Here's a Fiddle that shows this: http://jsfiddle.net/hA4eD/1/

In my computer, using Chrome's Dev tools, the text input has a height of exactly 32 pixels while the button input has a height of 28.79999... pixels. How do I make them equal without manually adjusting the number of pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the inputs have inherent borders that you're not taking into account. You can change them to have the same borders via CSS but this ends up making the controls look far uglier (Or leaves you specifically styling each input's borders & adjusting your heights accordingly, meaning you'll end up managing all the different styles).

One option is to use the -webkit-appearance css rule to disable this as others have suggested. Alternatively you can set `box-sizing: border-box;` to tell the CSS that the height you've specified should be the entire height of the input, borders included.

Answer (score 2):

please add webkit appearance property as none value...

Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/hA4eD/3/

```
input{
height:2em;
width:5em;
display:inline-block;
-webkit-appearance: none;/*new property*/
}
```

Comment: There is still a difference in the 2 elements: http://jsfiddle.net/hA4eD/7/, thanks for the response though.